# If statement is not excuting the statements in the correct order

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am trying to validate my android Edit text box so that when the button is pressed if the Edit Text box is empty a message will appear, i am also validating the Edit text box to make sure that the value entered is a number, if the text box is empty the error message will appear saying that the value must be a number, I think it has something to do with the structure of my if statements but im not sure what. the code below is what i have tried already.

```
TextView Display;
EditText Input;

Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOutput);
Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eName);

try{
    String UserInput = Input.getText().toString();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(UserInput);

    if(!UserInput.isEmpty()){
        if(number == (int) number){
            Display.setText(UserInput);
        }
    }else{
        Display.setText("Please enter a value into the text box");
    }
}catch(Exception  e){
    Display.setText("Please enter a number");
}
```

Comment: `if (number == (int) number)` while `number` is already an int?

Comment: im parsing through the User Input which is stored in a string called UserInput

Comment: `if(number == (int) number)` is a useless statement, it will always be true. it is like comparing `x == x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem arises from the fact that `Integer.parseInt()` will throw `NumberFormatException` for an empty string, sending control flow into the catch block before the if-statement even runs.

Re-order the empty check prior to parsing as a integer to fix.

```
String UserInput = Input.getText().toString();

if(!UserInput.isEmpty()){
    try{
        int number = Integer.parseInt(UserInput);

        Display.setText(UserInput);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        Display.setText("Please enter a number");
    }
}else{
    Display.setText("Please enter a value into the text box");
}
```

For the proper android way to filter for numerical values only consider adding the `android:inputType=number` propety to your EditText element in your layout XML or or via:

```
EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

directly in java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the input whether the user has inputted number and not alpha numeric value which you could do as below:

```
String userInput = null;
do {
     Display.setText("Please enter a number"); 
     userInput = Input.getText().toString();
} while (!userInput.isEmpty() && !userInput.matches("[0-9]+"));
Display.setText(userInput);
```

Above do while loop is to make sure that user has inputted the data and its a valid input. If that's not the case, then keep on getting the user input.

And finally once, its a valid number, just display the input number.

Answer (score 0):

> if the text box is empty the error message will appear saying that the value must be a number

The problem is in this snippet:

```
try{
    String UserInput = Input.getText().toString();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(UserInput);

    if(!UserInput.isEmpty()){
```

You're trying to convert the input to integer, before you're checking if there is a value available. That means you might try to convert an empty String: `""`. This doesn't work and `Integer#parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if that happens. This will lead you to the `catch` block and it will print *"Please enter a number"*.

To fix that, just check if `UserInput` is empty first, then try to convert the input to an integer:

```
String userInput = input.getText().toString();
if (!userInput.isEmpty()) {
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(userInput); // no need to store that result in a variable
        display.setText(userInput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        display.setText("Please enter a number");
    }
} else {
    display.setText("Please enter a value into the text box");
}
```

Also, please read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), because every variable should start with a lower case letter. I've already changed your variable names in my code sample.

Answer (score 0):

This 2 helper methods can help you:

1. Check if edittext has text. If edittext doesn't has text is set error message

   ```
   public static boolean hasText(Context context, EditText editText)
   {
   boolean validated = true;
   String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
   if (text.length() == 0)
   {
       editText.setText(text);
       validated = false;
       Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.alert_small);
       d.setBounds(0, 0, 
               d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
       editText.setError(context.getString(R.string.required_field), d);
   }
   else
   {
       editText.setError(null);
   }
   return validated;
   }
   ```
2. Check if text is number

   ```
   public static boolean isNumber(String str)
   {
   try
   {
       int d = Integer.parseInt(str);
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
   {
       return false;
   }
   return true;
   ```

   }